WSClock Page Replacement Algorithm
From my understanding, the basic Clock algorithm goes around setting the reference bit from 1 to 0 and unmapping a page until it encounters a page with the reference bit already as 0 in which case it loads it into the disk and replaces it with a new page.
The WSClock is meant to be an improvement on this by taking into account timestamps where we don't remove pages with the reference bits set to 0 that were accessed recently. However, where I find this algorithm dubious is that we have to set the reference bit of every page to 0 on every periodic clock interrupt. Isn't this extremely slow?
